# A trigonometric series with differences of cosines of cube roots

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

To be honest I don't know how to start working with this series. I can't even tell if the limit of the general term is $0$. Any help would be appreciated.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\cos\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+\sqrt{n}+7}\right)-\cos\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3-2\sqrt{n}+3}\right)\right).$$

Comment: We want $\cos x-\cos y$. Note that $2\sin a\sin b=\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)$. Set $a-b=x$, $a+b=y$. So $b=(y-x)/2$ and $|\sin b|$ is small, while $\sin a$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $n$ big enough we have:
$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+\sqrt{n}+7}-n \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}+7}{3 n^2}\leq \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$
and:
$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+\sqrt{n}+7} - \sqrt[3]{n^3-2\sqrt{n}+3} \leq \frac{3}{2n^{3/2}}.\tag{1}$$
Since the cosine function is Lipschitz continuous, the previous inequality implies:
$$\left|\cos\sqrt[3]{n^3+\sqrt{n}+7} - \cos\sqrt[3]{n^3-2\sqrt{n}+3}\right|\leq\frac{3}{2n^{3/2}},\tag{2}$$
so the given series is absolutely convergent.